# A JavaScript error occured in the main process while trying to run GeoGebra 6 Portable

Tags: error-handling, javascript

I recently downloaded [this](https://download.geogebra.org/package/linux-port6) version of GeoGebra and, after I extract the components of the zip file, everytime I try to launch it through terminal using `./GeoGebra` it gives me the following error:

```
 A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module './ggb-config.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/home/<username>/Downloads/GeoGebra-linux-x64/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<username>/Downloads/GeoGebra-linux-x64/resources/app/main.js:19:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<username>/Downloads/GeoGebra-linux-x64/resources/app/main.js:375:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

Answer (score 1):

This fix worked for me :

```
sudo touch /usr/share/geogebra-classic/resources/app/ggb-config.js
```

for the same error with geogebra-classic_6.0.400.0-201711172340_amd64.deb version, found [here](http://www.geogebra.org/download/deb.php?arch=amd64&ver=6).

source : https://help.geogebra.org/topic/geogebra-classic_6-0-400-0-201711172340_amd64-deb-is-broken